# Python selenium : Enter date in input box

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to enter date into an input box but it results into date getting appended to the default value - ultimately resulting into an invalid date and therefore returning to default value.Before entering the date, I'm deleting the default value but it doesn't seem to work. As you will see in the image, default value is today's date and I'm entering date of '07-09-2020' (9jul2020). How do I make the date selection work?

```
datefieldfrom = browser.find_element_by_name('reportDateStart')
datefieldfrom.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
sleep(1)
datefieldfrom.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
sleep(1)
datefieldfrom.send_keys(report_date)
```

```
<input name="reportDateStart" class="input-small date-field" type="text" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" value="07-13-2020" data-date-format="MM-dd-yyyy" autocomplete="off">
```

[image]

Comment: I'd try and avoid using `send_keys` where you can.  You should be able to set the value of that element directly - something like `datefieldfrom.text = report_date` (or maybe it's `datefieldfrom.innerHtml = report_date`).

Comment: @BruceWayne, ```datefieldfrom.text``` throws error and ```datefieldfrom.innerHtml``` does not have any impact, that is it does change the date

Comment: `datefieldfrom.setAttribute("value", report_date)`?